# Splitting string from file and then storing into a structure

Tags: c, file, strtok

I have data structure I have to add into a linked list. The data structure would come from a file with an input like this for example:

```
I0001|Item 1|Item 1 Desc|3.50|50
I0002|Item 2|Item 2 Desc|3.00|20
I0003|Item 3|Item 3 Desc|4.00|10
```

The structure:

```
typedef struct stock
{
    char id[ID_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    char name[NAME_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    char desc[DESC_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    Price price;
    unsigned onHand;
} Stock;
```

My code so far is this:

```
Boolean loadStock(VmSystem * system, const char * fileName)
{
    Stock data;
    char id[ID_LEN + NULL_SPACE], name[NAME_LEN + NULL_SPACE], desc[DESC_LEN + NULL_SPACE];
    FILE *fp;
    char str[200], *token;

    if((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL)
    {
         printf("File loaded\n");
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Cannot open file");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp) == NULL)
    {
        perror("failed to read from file");
        return FALSE;
    }

    while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(str, "|");
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            /** DO SOMETHING HERE **/
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL,"|");

        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
if(i%5 == 0)
{
strcpy(id, token);
}
else if(i%5 == 1)
{
    strcpy(name, token);
}
else if(i%5 == 2)
{
    strcpy(desc, token);
}

printf("%s\n", id);
token = strtok(NULL,"|");
i++;
memset(id, '\0', sizeof(id));
memset(name, '\0', sizeof(name));
memset(desc, '\0', sizeof(desc));
```

I am having some issues taking the token and using it to store values into the structure

Comment: I suggest you don't do the "tokenization" in a loop, but instead in a simple serial way, with five calls to `strtok` after each-other. And then copy the token into the correct structure member.

Answer (score 0):

You could read each line from the file with `fgets()` into a string `str` and use `sscanf()` to read from that string.

I assume that `Price` is a `typedef` for `float`.

Let `s` be a variable of type `struct stock`.

```
char str[200], pt[2][20];
Stock s;
fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);
sscanf(str, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]", s.id, s.name, s.desc, pt[0], pt[1]);
```

The `%[^|]` means read till encountering a `|`. Read more about it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)

The `price` and `onHand` elements are stored in `pt[0]` and `pt[1]` respectively in string form.
String conversion to `float` is done using [`strtof()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) while conversion to `unsigned long` is done using [`strtoul()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtoul.htm)

```
s.price=strtof(pt[0], NULL);
s.onHand=strtoul(pt[1], NULL, 10);
```

If you are worried about using `strtoul()`, which returns an `unsigned long int` instead of an `unsigned int`, you could first check if the value returned by `strtoul()` is greater than [`UINT_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/). 
`UINT_MAX` is the maximum value that can be stored in an `unsigned int`.
It is defined in `limits.h`.